# how to save the virtual desktops in windows like workspaces in ubuntu and some of the other linux distros?

Tags: windows

I know about multi tasking in Windows. But after a restart the virtual desktops are remaining the same but not the windows that were opened in the desktops. I have researched for a while but all are telling how to use but i want to save the sessions

Comment: The latest Windows Insider build has a Start --> Power option to restart apps when signing in.  I know that probably doesn't help much, though.  I also do not know if it restarts the apps in each virtual desktop or it puts them on the main desktop.

Comment: not working @xofz :(